# UWP Access Denied In Visual Studio

Tags: uwp

[image]When UWP debug it's show error message "Access Denied when debugging on Local Machine"

Thank you so much.

Comment: try to run vs as admin, if not works,there may be chances your antivirus program protect program from launch- then open windows defender security center. goto> Virus & thread protection.
Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.

Comment: That both didn't work.

Comment: okz! tried x86 debugging ? if not try after placing yout project to different e.g public folder

Comment: that on didn't work.

Comment: @SHAMALMANOJ Is it the first time that are trying to debug an UWP app? When you create a blank new UWP app, what's the result? Do you have this problem before?